# Combining Sample Means and Variances

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Let us assume we have several samples of unknown size but known mean value $\mu_{i}(x)$ and known variance $\sigma_{i}^{2}$. Now we want to calculate the mean value and variance for the total population.

The mean values should IMHO just be weighted with the reciprocal variances:

$w_{i}=\frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2} \cdot \sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2}}} \Rightarrow \mu(x) = \sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2}}} \mu_{i}(x)$

This looks and feels right and logical and I have seen similar answers to similar questions.

However I am not sure whether it is correct to calculate the new variance in the same simple way and I have not yet been able to find an answer with a decent explanation.

My Idea:

$\sigma^{2} = \mu(x^2) - \mu(x)^2 = \sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2} \cdot \sum\frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2}}} \mu_{i}(x)^2 - [\sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2} \cdot \sum\frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2}}} \mu_{i}(x)]^2$

Apart from the expressions probably not being completely simplified is this statistically sound or did I make some stupid mistake?

Comment: No, they are unequal and of unknown size.
Else there would hardly be a "problem". :)

Comment: If the samples are homoscedastic, their variances are inversely proportional to their size. This gives you the estimate of the sizes.

Comment: Thx for the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I still do not understand how to calculate the combined variance. 

My formula above is incorrect. 


How can I calculate the mean of square $\mu(x^2)$ from the mean sample values and their variances?

Just using $\sum_{i}w_{i}\mu_{i}^{2}$ ignores the old variances.
On the other hand trying to include them by adding $\sum_{i}w_{i}\sigma_{i}^{2}$ is obviously stupid as this is $1$ for any input. How do I weight and average the variances?